# postman http get request with authentification fails with 401 reply

Tags: http, digest-authentication

I have an IOT device (PV inverter). As with many of these there is an official API mostly for data retrival and some settings. However, given the right credentials (admin account) you can configure significantly more in the webinterface.

I would like to be able to do this from my home automation server directly (via node red finally). So I tried to have a look at the communication between the browser and the inverter via Wireshark.
I found some GET an POST calls, and wanted to start with the replication of a GET call via node-red or Postman first.

However, no matter what I tried so far I only get 401 replies.
Seemingly, I'm not able to setup the message with proper authentificaion. In wireshark the Postman and the original GET request are very close.

Here is the original (followed by a "200 OK" response):

> Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.0.64, Dst: 192.168.0.5
> Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 56183, Dst Port: 80, Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 601
> Source Port: 56183
> Destination Port: 80
> [Stream index: 1]
> [Conversation completeness: Incomplete (28)]
> [TCP Segment Len: 601]
> Sequence Number: 1    (relative sequence number)
> Sequence Number (raw): 2463465501
> [Next Sequence Number: 602    (relative sequence number)]
> Acknowledgment Number: 1    (relative ack number)
> Acknowledgment number (raw): 1894190984
> 0101 .... = Header Length: 20 bytes (5)
> Flags: 0x018 (PSH, ACK)
> [TCP Flags: ·······AP···]
> Window: 512
> [Calculated window size: 512]
> [Window size scaling factor: -1 (unknown)]
> Checksum: 0x8409 [unverified]
> [Checksum Status: Unverified]
> Urgent Pointer: 0
> [Timestamps]
> [SEQ/ACK analysis]
> TCP payload (601 bytes)
> Hypertext Transfer Protocol
> GET /commands/StandbyState HTTP/1.1\r\n
> Host: 192.168.0.5\r\n
> Connection: keep-alive\r\n
> Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*\r\n
> Authorization: Digest username="technician", realm="Webinterface area",
> nonce="63af2777:24350f8b8a09fb90b82b6ac480d325cc", uri="/commands/StandbyState", response="a09ac5fe504563040d0ff8acfd68653e", qop=auth, nc=00000022, cnonce="NaN"\r\n
>
> > ```
> >     username="technician"  
> >     realm="Webinterface area"  
> >     nonce="63af2777:24350f8b8a09fb90b82b6ac480d325cc"  
> >     uri="/commands/StandbyState"  
> >     response="a09ac5fe504563040d0ff8acfd68653e"  
> >     qop=auth  
> >     nc=00000022
> > ```
>
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
> Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36\r\n
> Referer: [http://192.168.0.5/\r\n](http://192.168.0.5/%5Cr%5Cn)
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n
> Accept-Language: de-DE,de;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7\r\n
> \r\n
> [Full request URI: http://192.168.0.5/commands/StandbyState]

and here is the captured Postman packet

> Internet Protocol Version 4, Src: 192.168.0.64, Dst: 192.168.0.5
> Transmission Control Protocol, Src Port: 43404, Dst Port: 80, Seq: 1, Ack: 1, Len: 471
> Source Port: 43404
> Destination Port: 80
> [Stream index: 5]
> [Conversation completeness: Incomplete, DATA (15)]
> [TCP Segment Len: 471]
> Sequence Number: 1    (relative sequence number)
> Sequence Number (raw): 990556558
> [Next Sequence Number: 472    (relative sequence number)]
> Acknowledgment Number: 1    (relative ack number)
> Acknowledgment number (raw): 2175082347
> 0101 .... = Header Length: 20 bytes (5)
> Flags: 0x018 (PSH, ACK)
> [TCP Flags: ·······AP···]
> Window: 513
> [Calculated window size: 131328]
> [Window size scaling factor: 256]
> Checksum: 0x8387 [unverified]
> [Checksum Status: Unverified]
> Urgent Pointer: 0
> [Timestamps]
> [SEQ/ACK analysis]
> TCP payload (471 bytes)
> Hypertext Transfer Protocol
> GET /commands/StandbyState HTTP/1.1\r\n
> [truncated]Authorization: Digest username="technician", realm="Webinterface area", nonce="63af2777:24350f8b8a09fb90b82b6ac480d325cc", uri="/commands/StandbyState", algorithm="MD5", qop=auth, nc=00000022, cnonce="NaN", response="a09ac5fe5
>
> > ```
> >     username="technician"  
> >     realm="Webinterface area"  
> >     nonce="63af2777:24350f8b8a09fb90b82b6ac480d325cc"  
> >     uri="/commands/StandbyState"  
> >     algorithm="MD5"  
> >     qop=auth  
> >     nc=00000022  
> >     cnonce="NaN"
> > ```
>
> User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.30.0\r\n
> Accept: */*\r\n
> Postman-Token: e5d8ee2c-37fb-49ae-aa37-1cf05bfe8608\r\n
> Host: 192.168.0.5\r\n
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br\r\n
> Connection: keep-alive\r\n
> \r\n
> [Full request URI: http://192.168.0.5/commands/StandbyState]
> [HTTP request 1/1]

Why does this not work?

Comment: `cnonce="NaN"` seems to be your pblm

Comment: Sadly no - I can leave it open, set it to anything else or NaN ... result stays the same

Comment: The `nonce` value should change with every request (it is what stops hackers replaying captured requests). The nonce value is supplied by the server when it rejects the first request

Comment: ist there a system to generate new nonce values? I just changed a few digits of the original one to create a new one - the reply stays at 401

Comment: The nonce is generated by the server you are connecting to NOT the client. The client tries to connect, gets a 401 error which includes the new nonce value to be used to generate the DISGEST auth response to try again with. I suggest you look up how HTTP Digest auth works.